# Multiple variants nonlinear regression

Tags: non-linear-regression

I plan to work on the multiple variants nonlinear regression using machine learning techniques. The output equation should be like: Z = a * X^b * Y^c. The inputs are X and Y, or even more, and Z is output. Would anyone recommend some toolbox in Python? I appreciate that.

I found a lot linear regression method. But not specific this one.

Comment: Use `curve_fit` from `scipy.optimize` or `Scikit-learn`